# Как получить изображение по размеру в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Вот код PHP

```
<?php global $post; ?>
<?php $about_promo = acf_get_option('about_promo', $post->ID); ?>
<?php if(!empty($about_promo)): ?>
    <section class="promo_about_company" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($about_promo['bg']); ?>)">
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Вот код в functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'tab_sizes', 767, 600, true );
```

Как вывести картинку с размером 'tab_sizes'? Делаю так не получается

```
<section class="promo_about_company" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($about_promo['bg']['tab_sizes']); ?>)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы конечно рекомендовал вам проверить что за данные приходят в массиве **$about_promo** и для понимания не помешало бы понимать все-таки что это за опция такая, вы используете ACF Group или что-то другое, внутри чего и есть ваше поле с картинкой.

В любом случае, обычно размеры изображений содаржатся внутри массива **sizes** это в том случае, если вы в своем поле возвращаете массив, а не ID. Должно быть что-то вроде

```
<?php    
$image = get_field('image');
$image['sizes']['tab_sizes']; // Ваш размер изображения
```

В том же случае если вы используете ID, то получение URL изображения будет выглядеть таким образом

```
<?php
$image = get_field('image');
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image, 'tab_sizes' ); // URL вашего изображения
```